# rs/pushd crashes when a new subscriber is received

Tags: node.js, push-notification, redis

I'm trying to use https://github.com/rs/pushd as a push notification server.

Whenever I try to add a new subscriber, the server crashes with this stack trace:

```
/home/ec2-user/push_server/pushd/node_modules/redis/index.js:602
                throw err;
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null
  at /home/ec2-user/push_server/pushd/lib/api.coffee:20:21
  at /home/ec2-user/push_server/pushd/lib/subscriber.coffee:133:21
  at try_callback (/home/ec2-user/push_server/pushd/node_modules/redis/index.js:592:9)
  at RedisClient.return_reply (/home/ec2-user/push_server/pushd/node_modules/redis/index.js:685:13)
  at HiredisReplyParser.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/push_server/pushd/node_modules/redis/index.js:321:14)
  at HiredisReplyParser.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at HiredisReplyParser.execute (/home/ec2-user/push_server/pushd/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/hiredis.js:43:18)
  at RedisClient.on_data (/home/ec2-user/push_server/pushd/node_modules/redis/index.js:547:27)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/push_server/pushd/node_modules/redis/index.js:102:14)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
  at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
  at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:529:21)
```

This is the command that should add a new subscriber (example from the documentation), and causes the crash:

```
curl -d proto=apns -d token=FE66489F304DC75B8D6E8200DFF8A456E8DAEACEC428B427E9518741C92C6660 -d lang=fr -d badge=0 -d category=show -d contentAvailable=true http://localhost/subscribers
```

The crash happens before the subscriber is added to the database.

The server is a RHEL micro instance on AWS

Versions

Redis Server 2.8.19.

Node.js 0.10.36.

CoffeeScript 1.9.0

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/lib/event.coffee
-        throw new Error("Missing redis connection") if not redis?
+        throw new Error("Missing redis connection") if not @redis?
/lib/subscriber.coffee
-                if info?.updated? # subscriber exists
+                if @info?.updated? # subscriber exists
                     # transform numeric value to number type
-                    for own key, value of info
+                    for own key, value of @info
```